# How get one line per key in left outer join

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

The context is a transaction table with date and UserAccount. This table contains about billion lines.

```
dOperationValueDate  sUserAccount                                  
-------------------  ----------------------------------------------
2016-03-05           00000000001                                   
2016-03-06           00000000002                                   
2016-03-07           00000000003                                   
2016-03-08           00000000004                                   
2016-03-09           00000000005                                   
2016-04-05           00000000002                                   
2016-10-05           00000000001                                   
2016-10-06           00000000001                                   
2016-10-06           00000000005
```

I would like to find datas in my table with these criterias :

- At least one transaction before 6 months ago (like TOP 1 *)
- No transaction for 6 months

In my example, the results would be accounts 2, 3, 4.

I started with a LEFT OUTER JOIN, in order to remove all userId with transaction since 6 months. But the processing time is just horrible : for 4 hours right now.

```
SELECT b.sUserAccount FROM
(SELECT sUserAccount FROM T_Operations WITH (readuncommitted) WHERE dOperationValueDate < DATEADD(month, -6, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETUTCDATE()), 0)) GROUP BY sUserAccount) b -- all operations before 6 months ago
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT sUserAccount FROM T_Operations WITH (readuncommitted) WHERE dOperationValueDate >= DATEADD(month, -6, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETUTCDATE()), 0)) GROUP BY sUserAccount) c -- all operations since 6 months
ON b.sUserAccount = c.sUserAccount
WHERE c.sUserBankAccount IS NULL) d -- remove all customers who have operations before 6 months ago and since 6 months / keep only customers who have operations beofre 6 months ago only
```

I think the solution is to find only one operation in the b query, and sql stops when it find one row. The main problem is only if the user doesn't have transaction before 6 months ago but for the others, it will be fine.

On the other hand, I have to check each transaction since 6 months in order to remove customers from the scope.

I read about CROSS APPLY, but I'm not sure about how it works.

The main problem here is the processing time. I have to do a "quick" request (less than 1 hour).

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Do you happen to have a single index composed of `sUserAccount` and `dOperationValueDate` (in that order)? (Are those faux-Hungarian notation column names?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should be able to just use NOT EXISTS here.

```
SELECT  b.sUserAccount
FROM    T_Operations b WITH (READUNCOMMITTED)
WHERE   b.dOperationValueDate < DATEADD(month,-6,DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,0,GETUTCDATE()),0))
        AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                         FROM   T_Operations WITH (READUNCOMMITTED)
                         WHERE  sUserAccount = b.sUserAccount
                                AND dOperationValueDate >= DATEADD(month,-6,DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,0,GETUTCDATE()),0)) )
GROUP BY b.sUserAccount -- all operations before 6 months ago
```

or actually, you might be able to just use GROUP BY with HAVING

```
SELECT  sUserAccount
FROM    T_Operations WITH (READUNCOMMITTED)
GROUP BY sUserAccount
HAVING  MAX(dOperationValueDate) < DATEADD(month,-6,DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,0,GETUTCDATE()),0))
```

as a side note.. `DATEADD(month,-6,DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,0,GETUTCDATE()),0))` would return `2016-04-01`

if you want current date, minus six months you can use `DATEADD(month,-6,CAST(GETUTCDATE() AS DATE))` or `DATEADD(month,-6,DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,0,GETUTCDATE()),0)`

Comment: @BaptX  try the second option that uses HAVING

Comment: I like the second option. I will make some perf tests.

Comment: Your second method takes only 3 minutes, while Paparazzi method takes 4 minutes, while mine takes... 89 minutes :O

Answer (score 0):

```
datatime @dt = DATEADD(month, -6, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETUTCDATE()), 0));
SELECT sUserAccount 
FROM T_Operations WITH (readuncommitted) 
WHERE dOperationValueDate < @dt
EXCEPT
SELECT sUserAccount 
FROM T_Operations WITH (readuncommitted) 
WHERE dOperationValueDate >= @dt;
```

Have an index on dOperationValueDate